# Is the classpath order of ant loadproperties guaranteed

Tags: ant

I'm trying to load a property file that can exist in a custom config directory and/or in a default config directory.
The custom config should take precedence over the default config.

```
+- defaultconfig
   * build.properties 
+- customconfig
   * build.properties <- this file should get loaded
```

I found I can use

```
<loadproperties resource="build.properties" classpath="defaultconfig,customconfig" />
```

to achieve that.

To my surprise I needed to put customconfig after defaultconfig in the classpath.

**Is the order in which the files are searched always from last path to the first ?**
Or is this unreliable